# Macfusion - how can I auto connect on boot?

Tags: macos

I have Macfusion automatically running when I boot, but how can I have it automatically connect to a server?  Can't find this anywhere..

Comment: [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/)'s disc mode is a far better implementation than MacFusion. It has some [bugs](https://twitter.com/nuc/status/47945970817830912) though :(

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of MacOS, you may be able to use [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) to create a startup script that runs after you login to your mac.  You will likely need to figure out a command line equivalent to whatever you currently do in the finder to connect to a server.  Run that command in the terminal to verify it works, then create a script using Lingon to execute the command immediately after you login to your Mac.

The project used to be hosted on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/), but "as of 2009-07-06, […] is no longer under active development". See new link above.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out MacFusion is garbage just in case anyone wondered so I abandoned this idea and went back to Cyberduck

Comment: It would be better if you entered this answer as a comment in your own question though..

Comment: What are the specific aspects that make of macfusion such an non-usable piece of software? Just curious.